# Check that a string contains only ASCII characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I check that a string only contains ASCII characters in Python? Something like Ruby's `ascii_only?`

I want to be able to tell whether string specific data read from file is in ascii

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Python 3.7 were added methods which do what you want:

> `str`, `bytes`, and `bytearray` gained support for the new [`isascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isascii) method, which can be used to test if a string or bytes contain only the ASCII characters.

---

Otherwise:

```
>>> all(ord(char) < 128 for char in 'string')
True
>>> all(ord(char) < 128 for char in 'строка')
False
```

Another version:

```
>>> def is_ascii(text):
    if isinstance(text, unicode):
        try:
            text.encode('ascii')
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            return False
    else:
        try:
            text.decode('ascii')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return False
    return True
... 
>>> is_ascii('text')
True
>>> is_ascii(u'text')
True
>>> is_ascii(u'text-строка')
False
>>> is_ascii('text-строка')
False
>>> is_ascii(u'text-строка'.encode('utf-8'))
False
```

Comment: I think this will always create an entire list? It uses more memory, and will be slower if the first character is a >0x80 character since it keeps iterating over the entire string (which doesn't matter too much in *most* applications, but does in *some*).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker >I think this will always create an entire list? < No, it won't. The expression inside `all` is a generator, which feeds characters one by one.

Comment: Which is faster and has less time complexity? or both are the same?

Comment: @JavaSa, time complexity should be the same. Which one is faster - you should measure. I suspect that for bigger strings encode/decode version is faster - it's implemented in C.

Comment: Is there any way to leverage `mypy` (http://www.mypy-lang.org) to static-type-check type-hinted string literals to `byte` types to support this effort (at `mypy`-check time) instead of relying only on run-time methods (which I understand is what's happening in this answer--pls correct me if I misunderstand)?

Answer (score 6):

If you have unicode strings you can use the "encode" function and then catch the exception:

```
try:
    mynewstring = mystring.encode('ascii')
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print("there are non-ascii characters in there")
```

If you have bytes, you can import the chardet module and check the encoding:

```
import chardet

# Get the encoding
enc = chardet.detect(mystring)['encoding']
```

Comment: You should catch the `UnicodeDecodeError` error that you're expecting, not the base `Exception` class. Consider what would happen if for whatever reason `chardet.detect` doesn't have a `encoding` key, or if `mystring` would be a `list` or `int`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also opt for regex to check for only ascii characters. `[\x00-\x7F]` can match a single ascii character:

```
>>> OnlyAscii = lambda s: re.match('^[\x00-\x7F]+$', s) != None
>>> OnlyAscii('string')
True
>>> OnlyAscii('Tannh‰user')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to your problem would be to try and encode the string in a particular encoding. 
For example:

```
'H€llø'.encode('utf-8')
```

This will throw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now you can catch the "UnicodeDecodeError" to determine that the string did not contain  just the ASCII characters.

```
try:
    'H€llø'.encode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print 'This string contains more than just the ASCII characters.'
```